My ISPICKVAL formula is never true
I try to use a row-level formula in a report:
IF(ispickval(Opportunity.Account.ClassLevel1__c, "End User"), Opportunity.Amount.CONVERT, 0)

But the value is always 0. I have no idea what I do wrong.
The idea is to count only if customer class = Enduser.
BR

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Are you sure the formula matches the picklist value?  Is it End User or Enduser?

Also double-check the Picklist value vs its label

Not sure if formulas are case-sensitive as well, but that is another thing to check.

Hi guys, thanks for you reply.
I found the issue. The formula expects the value "EU" to become true. I proved it with the text() formula
